# Entropy on interacting particles and objects

Tags: entropy

I am not seeing a lot of discussion on this top, which is why I am bring it up.
Entropy is observed for non-interacting particles; No surprise there. But, for interacting particles or objects, entropy does not seem to always apply. For example, throw random piles of magnets together. Salt crystal forming cubes when water evaporates. Water molecules form snowflakes below subzero temperature. Chemical reactions in general and the infamous Miller–Urey experiment (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Urey_experiment).
Please share your thought on this. Thank you.